# Настройка VPS, установка PHP, mysql ...

Tags: vds, php, openvz, сервер, vps

Где можно найти подробную инструкцию(или несколько) по установке Apache и других элементов?

Перерыл уже куча статей, в одной говорят что апач нужно удалять в другой ещё куча приколов. Установил и удалил все уже по несколько раз, целый день играюсь, PHP вроде работает но на следующих этапах все сбивалось.

Ну или хотяб подскажите что за чем ставить и что нужно, а что не очень.

> `Virtualization Type - OpenVZ
> RAM - 128M
> Disk Space - 10 GB
> Operating System - Ubuntu 13.04 64bit
> VSwap - 128 MB`

Comment: Может вы конкретизируете, что и где у вас не получилось? Расписывать тут все пошагово и с картинками вам никто не будет.

Comment: @huffman, ну хотяб последовательность установки элементов можете написать? Например 'apache -> php...', не думаю что там много.

Comment: @TANKIST,  если вы хотите получить конкретное описание того, что и в какой последовательности вам нужно поставить то вам нужно конкретно описать, что вы хотите получить на выходе. В любых других случаях вы потерпите не удачу и потратите время.

Comment: Не рановато ли вам заниматься всем этим на реальном хостинге? Деньги на ветер. Сначала надо бы подучить матчасть, чтобы знать как вообще работает вебсервер. Без обид.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

во-1, параметры сервера у вас не ахти. На таком объеме памяти мало что из необходимого софта развернется корректно.
во-2, православнее для веб-сервера все-таки Сентос, и для такого объема памяти 64бита особой роли не сыграет.
во-3, вот это вот ваше: "и других элементов", "на следующих этапах все сбивалось", "и что нужно, а что не очень" -- требует мощных телепатических способностей, а телепаты все еще в отпуске :)
во-4, судя по этой фразе "не думаю что там много" -- вам еще явно рано заниматься такими вещами.

Comment: Нас счет "не думаю что там много" я говорил что не долго писать список софта, а не описывать как ставить сам софт

Comment: я вспомнил одну штуку, которая может вам помочь!!! вот эта панель - http://www.vestacp.com/#install при своей установке добавляет нужные репо и сама разворачивает и нджинкс, и апач, и пхп и мускл. но! параметры сервера желательно повыше и сентос, а не дебиан.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы рекомендовал [ставить](http://www.nevedimko.ru/linux/linux-ustanovka-webminvirtualmin-v-debian.html#more-37) [Virtualmin](http://www.webmin.com/virtualmin.html), раз у вас такие затруднения, и плясать уже от него. Но конфигурация действительно крайне слабая.

Answer (score 2):

Устанавливайте по любому мануалу в сети. Вот [по этому](http://linux.odessa.ua/ustanovka-apache-php-mysql-phpmyadmin-v-ubuntu/) например. Если что-то конкретно не получается, лучше об этом написать в вопросе.

Answer (score -1):

Вот хорошая и подробная инструкция по настройке LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP):
http://ru.wh-db.com/article/ustanovka-i-nastroyka-web-servera-dla-sayta-v-ubuntu/